# Enterprise Wiki with metadata navigation is showing many errors and problems:-

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am trying to create an Enterprise Wiki which have a metadata navigation and filtering, I though the requirement is straight forward in SharePoint 2013, but I have fall into a number of problems and bugs:-

1. First for all I have enabled the “Metadata Navigation and Filtering” service on the site level.
2. I define the intended Term store from “Term Store Management”.
3. Then from the “Metadata navigation settings  ” at the library level I define navigation using wiki Category.
4. Then I have linked the Wiki Category site Colum to use the term store.
5. The first problem is that the metadata navigation did not show up so I had to manually add a reference to the navigation using the SharePoint designer and I have edited the page layout.

   - I Put this markup in the beginning of the page

     **<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="MetadataNavTree" src="~/_controltemplates/MetadataNavTree.ascx" %>**
   - I Put this code in the end of page’s code, after the next  tag

But now I fall into these two problems:-

- When I click on any term inside the navigation tree it will always redirect to home page, instead of showing the wiki pages that are associated with this term.
- The metadata navigation tree will not be shown to contributor or reader users; only site administrator is able to see it.

Any idea of how to solve these problems?

BR
[image]